# comparing edittext input to string array

Tags: android, string, compare, android-edittext

Im new, so sorry if my question is lame.

But, im trying to make an AI chatbot (like, a simpler version of cleverbot that responds to certain input keywords.)

I have an edittext panel, which the user will input words to 'talk' to the AI. But, instead of coding every word in the java file, i want to compare the string input to an existing string array to check if the keyword is there and so that the AI can display the coressponding answer.

example:

> if input is: Hellothere!
>
> and on the string array, there is: Hello.

and:

> If edittext=Hello, then display this: blah blah.

Here is my (amateurish) code:

```
  public void onClick(View v){


        Resources res = getResources();
       String[] usernames = res.getStringArray(R.array.input2);
     boolean submit_check = input1(wordy, usernames); 
       public boolean input1(String wordy, String[] input2){

           if(candidate.equals(usernames))
           {


               wahh.start();
           myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.OUTPUT); 
           pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.keel);
            String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];   
            display.setText(q); 
           }

           else{ 
               wahh.start();
               pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.keel);
               myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.OUTPUT); 
            String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];   
            display.setText(q);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something more along the lines of this (pseudocode):

```
if(EditText.getText().Contains("Hello")) {
    EditText.setText("What's up?");
}
```

You'd want to check if it contains a selection from the array though. If it does, get the index of the array. Based on the index, respond accordingly. The easiest way to do that would be using a for loop and a switch statement. Although AI is actually a lot more complicated than this, and my knowledge.